# how do getUrl of controller in Adminhtml on frontend?

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I have custom module override product view. So in frontend I want to get action Save in `Custom/Controller/Adminhtml/Custom/Save`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use controllers from the backend on frontend and the other way around.
In order to use a controlled from the backend you need a valid backend session and you cannot get that on the frontend.

I advice you to create a method (in a helper or something) that does all the heavy lifting for saving your entity and have 2 controllers (one for backend, one for frontend) that call this common method.

Comment: +1 for separate method. In Magneto 2 it is better to avoid helpers and create services instead, for CRUD operations some repository should be created (similar to `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface`)

Comment: @AlexP. I agree. I did say "in a helper or something". :)  A helper is easier, but you are right. It should be avoided. A repository looks like the nice way to go.